# KMeans clustering for more than 5 million vectors

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have hit a real problem. I need to do some Kmeans clustering for  5 million vectors, each containing about 32 cols.
I tried out Mahout which requires linux and I am on windows, I am restrained from using a Linux OS and any sort of simulator.

Can anyone suggest a KMeans clustering algorithm that is scalable upto 5M vectors and can converge quickly?

I have tested a few but they wont scale. Which means they are slow and take forever to complete.

Thanks

Comment: how many clusters ? Euclidean, or a custom metric ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, So who ever wants clustering for large scale datasets, the only way of doing so is to use Mahout. IT requires a linux platform. So I had to use virtual box, placed Ubuntu on it and then used Mahout. Its a lengthy procedure to set up Mahout, but the two links that I used are as follows.

http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Running_Hadoop_On_Ubuntu_Linux_(Single-Node_Cluster)

http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Running_Hadoop_On_Ubuntu_Linux_(Multi-Node_Cluster)

Comment: Links are no longer correct, but you can find these guides easily with google.

Comment: The ending parenthesis should be the part of the URL. Above you can see that it is currently no highlighted as a part of the URL. Add it when to url in your browser and will take you to the page