# Is it possible to see the current iteration number in OpenCV's cvKmeans2?

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis, computer-vision, k-means

I'm trying to cluster a really large dataset - 3030764x162 into 4000 clusters using the cvKmeans2 function in OpenCV 2.1.
I would like to see which iteration the K-means algorithm is currently in (similar to what is displayed in Matlab), but I don't see any documentation that points to how I can do this.

It's kind of frustrating seeing a blank screen and not knowing when the code is going to terminate!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunate as it seems, the answer is No, you cannot. There are no debugging/informative statements anywhere in the kmeans function as provided by OpenCV. However, you may edit and add statements to the method as you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

@Sau,
May be you need some other way of doing it. Though my answer is not relevant to OpenCV. 
I have not tried in OpenCV, I had once done KMeans clustering for a extremely large data set and it was more a option better than OpenCV as it worked in a distributed mode. Though very lengthy, but still you might be interested. Its Kmeans clustering using [Mahout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403981/kmeans-clustering-for-more-than-5-million-vectors/3544673#3544673)

Check it out